# How to store content type structure (and paragraphs type) in a module

Tags: 8

I have a content type (made of field name, field type, field settings, etc...) that contains also a paragraph type field (entity revision reference field) and I would like to use it in some other projects.
My idea is to create a module and when this module is enabled, the content type (and paragraphs type) is added to the project.
Note 1: I don't want to store the data, only the structure
Note 2:This is a D8 question

Comment: Is this about providing yaml files in /config/install? There are many similar questions here, for example https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202626/install-a-module-that-creates-a-content-type-with-fileds-via-yaml. If not, can you be more specific?

Comment: Either config or Features.

Comment: @4x4 many thank for the link. I will try to follow the advice... I will export the config files from my running site to use them in my module. I will answer myself here if I suceed.